# How to return files with a specific file type only?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import os

def read_file(path):
    name_file = os.listdir(path)
    return name_file

path = "/home/ich/Schreibtisch/fotki"
print(read_file(path))
```

This returns only all files in a folder in a list. But I want them to end with `".jpg"`. There are many files in the folder (`.jpg`, `.txt`, ...), but I want that only the `.jpg` files.

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English language site. Please ask your questions in English only.

Comment: A list of them could be obtained using the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob) module. i.e. `jpg_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.jpg"))`. Note that the result will be an empty list if there are no files matching the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Do this with `os.listdir` and `.endswith`

```
import os

path = "/home/ich/Schreibtisch/fotki"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".jpg"):
        print(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Comment: I can only speculate but maybe the downvoter disliked the mild violation of the DRY principle (you repeat `'/mydir'`).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. By the way is there a book or good place to get an overview of such principles?

Comment: I believe that coders who care pick up these things over time automatically. However, if you must read a book, there are classics like Code Complete.